# Add a new line in xslt

Tags: xslt, line-breaks

How to add a new line inside XSLT, i have already tried `<xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>` but it didn't work, i also tried `<xsl:text></xsl:text>` it doesn't work everytime either. Isn't there another solution?
xml:

```
<composition>
            <ion type="positif">calcium 67.32mg/l</ion>
            <ion type="positif">magnésium 10.08mg/l</ion>
            <ion type="negatif">chlorure 20.82mg/l</ion>
            <ion type="negatif">nitrate 3.5mg/l</ion>
            <autre type="metal">fer</autre>
</composition>
```

xslt:

```
<tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="./bouteille/composition" >
      <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="./ion[@type='negatif']"/><xsl:text> <!-- Won't add a new line -->
           </xsl:text>
      </td>    
    </xsl:for-each>
</tr>
```

Comment: What does your <xsl:output> tag look like, if you have one? You can do `<xsl:text>` then a real newline, so that the closing tag starts at the beginning of the next line: `</xsl:text>`.

Comment: I have an `<xsl:value-of>` inside an html table column and i want a new line after that tag, I tried to put it in a `<xsl:text>` tag but it displays that `<xsl:text> must not contain child elements

Comment: If you are outputting html, then you should use the `<br />` tag to create a new line.

Comment: @Mina Please post a minimal, but complete, reproducible example of your XML and XSLT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example that you have posted is incomplete. The one thing that it makes clear, though, is that you are producing an HTML table. Therefore you should be using `<br/>` to create new lines within a table cell.

Probably something like:

```
<td>
    <xsl:for-each select="ion[@type='negatif']"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <br/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</td>
```

I'm afraid I can't be more exact than that with no context to draw upon.